# Over time losing connection to mysql server during queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I am running a discord bot using a MySQL server which are BOTH running on my UBUNTU 18.04 server. It works fine, but after a few hours I start to get an error any time I access the database.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/narnar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord_slash/client.py", line 1352, in invoke_command
    await func.invoke(ctx, **args)
  File "/home/narnar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord_slash/model.py", line 209, in invoke
    return await self.func(self.cog, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/narnar/cool-art/cogs/artlevels.py", line 120, in leaderboardCommand
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM artLevels")
  File "/home/narnar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 271, in execute
    raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)
  File "/home/narnar/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 522, in cmd_query
    sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Comment: Is the server wait_timeout exceeded? Defaults to 8 hrs. Probably could catch this exception and reconnect.

Comment: reconnect to what?

Comment: the MySQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by not having connections open for too long. My program connected to the MySQL server at the beginning of the program and used that same connection all the time. So instead of having one connection, I just opened a connection when I needed to access the database then closed it afterwards. Just make sure you don't have your connection open for too long

Don't do this:

```
con = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=host,
        user="ImNotThat",
        passwd="Stupid",
        database="toShowMyPasswords"
 )


async def someListenerEvent():
     doThing()
     con.commit()
```

Do this:

```
async def someListenerEvent():
    con = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=host,
        user="ImNotThat",
        passwd="Stupid",
        database="toShowMyPasswords"
    )
    doThing()
    con.commit()
    cur.close()
    con.close()
```